# Typescript idioms for defining externally configurable options

Tags: typescript, configuration, instantiation, idioms

What idioms are people using for defining configuration options in Typescript so that the option type definitions are available to other modules?

I'm coming from a background in Java, and the obvious thing for me to do -- put an inner type on a default export -- doesn't yet work due to [a bug in Typescript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14080):

```
export default class MyClass {

    constructor(opts: Options) {
        //...
    }
}

namespace MyClass {
    export interface Options {
        //...
    }
}
```

Instead, it seems that I have to either export `MyClass` and `Options` as siblings of the module or export them in separate modules as defaults.

The first of these solutions asks me to be extra-creative about naming a module that has only one class, since the module exposes an interface in addition to the class.

The second solution results in lots of extra modules/files, particularly because this is how Javascript programmers are used to configuring everything.

The only reasonable solution that comes to mind is as follows:

- Export the class and options interface as siblings of the same module.
- Name that module for the class (e.g. `myclass`).
- Elsewhere, `import { MyClass, Options as MyClassOptions } from 'myclass'`.

It could also be that the Typescript way is to export lots of classes from a single module, naming each uniquely for the caller's namespace. In that case, maybe people are doing something like, `import { MyClass, MyClassOptions } from 'bigmodule'`. Functional, but not ideal.

Googling around didn't give me insight into what people are actually doing. So what are the common idioms? Am I completely off track in how to employ option configuration in a Typescript world? Is some other model for configuring more prevalent? Dispense with named option types?

UPDATE #1: Why does it matter? Because I'm making a framework for publication on NPM, hoping others will find matters of configuration comfortably familiar.

UPDATE #2: I've learned that the above approach is close to something that works and that is more amenable to refactoring. The module would do this:

```
export class MyClass { // no default

    constructor(opts: Options) {
        //...
    }
}

export namespace MyClass { // with export
    export interface Options {
        //...
    }
}
```

And the client can cleanly and simply import as follows:

```
import { MyClass } from 'mymodule';

function getOptions(): MyClass.Options {
    //...
}
let obj = new MyClass(getOptions());
```

But I still have no idea what conventions might be in play. I'll report back as I learn various frameworks, unless someone can beat me to it.

Comment: It occurs to me that idioms of dependency injection could be upending these traditional approaches to configuration. I have yet to catch up on this trend.

Answer (score 1):

A module is not equal to a single class, it is a tightly related set of behaviour.

With this in mind, I would recommend your existing suggestion:

```
export class MyClass {
    constructor(opts: Options) {
        //...
    }
}

export interface Options {
    //...
}
```

## Naming

There is also a trick to naming things such as your module. Write a quick table of "things of the same kind" and then name your module after what you'd call those things.

For example, if you're class was called "Crisps", you'd expand it:

1. Crisps
2. Nuts
3. Pork Scratchings

And then you might name your module "Snacks".

## Big Modules

If you take care to put code together when it will change for the same reason, and separating it when it changes for a different reason, you shouldn't find yourself with big modules.

Comment: Thanks. That's the "big module" approach, which Java programmers have learned to avoid. In any case, some of my classes are big and there will be no other classes in the file simply for reasons of maintainability. Suppose it only makes sense to put one class in the module?

Comment: You don't get big modules by following a "tightly related set of behaviour". You get it when you fail to follow the SOLID principles, especially SRP, which is a fractal principle.

Comment: Gotcha. I admit there are times when I want to pack multiple public classes in one Java file. In any case, I'm looking for what the conventions are for Typescript, if any have been established. There are clearly several ways to pull it off.

Comment: If you take a look through common NPM modules, you'll see that modules usually contain a handful of "things". The key decision is still really about what is easy to maintain. Until your options interface is shared by multiple classes, it is actually better left in the same file as the single class that uses it. It gets erased by the compiler, so the JavaScript modules would only contain the class in this specific case. It isn't desirable to have a TypeScript file that just contains an interface.